# How to invalidate `password reset key` after being used

Tags: login, security, user-registration, password

I am trying to write my own lost password plugin. It is working perfectly. But how can I **invalidate** the reset key after being used once. Currently I am able to set new password as many times as I wish by clicking the reset password link sent to my email.

Apart from it, do I need to implement any security measures in below code?

**Password Reset Link generation and send via email:**

```php
$user = get_user_by('login', $_POST['username'] );

$token = base64_encode( serialize([
    'key' => get_password_reset_key( $user ),
    'user' => $user->user_login
]));           

$reset_pass_link = 'http://example.com/new-pass?action=new-pass&token='.$token;

$to = $user->user_email;
$subject = 'Your Password reset link';
$message = $reset_pass_link;
$headers[] = 'From: Example <admin@example.com>'."\r\n";

wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

**Validate Reset Key and then set new password :**

```php
$token = maybe_unserialize(base64_decode($_GET['token']));

if( !isset($token) || !isset($token['key']) || !isset($token['user']) ){

    $ajax_handler->add_error_message("Invalid Token.");
    $ajax_handler->is_success = false;
    return;
}


$key = $token['key'];
$user = $token['user'];


$user_id = get_user_by('login', $user)->ID;
$new_pass = $fields[$settings['ap_new_pass']];

if ( check_password_reset_key($key, $user)){

    wp_set_password( $new_pass, $user_id );
}
else{
    $ajax_handler->add_error_message("Invalid Token.");
    $ajax_handler->is_success = false;
    return;
}
```

Comment: After verification, set the $token array again, this time setting the key to something random that you'll never communicate to the user. It should then expire after 24h i believe. Or, clear the DB entry where the key is stored.

Comment: It didn't help me. As I know `wp_set_password( );` already resets the user_activation_key to empty.